# How to use navigation in main entry file of react?

Tags: reactjs

**This is my index file where i have implemented axios interceptors for refresh token**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "../src/routes";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookie from "js-cookie";
import { LOGOUT } from "./redux/slices/authSlice";

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if(error.config.url=="http://localhost:5000/api/refreshtoken" && error.response.status === 401){
      console.log("here we go")
      store.dispatch(LOGOUT())

   //I want to use navigation here something like this => navigate("/login) 
      
    }
   
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
     originalRequest._retry = true;

      const refreshToken = Cookie.get("refreshtoken");
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + refreshToken;
      return await axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/api/refreshtoken")
        .then((res) => {
          Cookie.remove("token");
          Cookie.set("token", res.data.access_token);
          Cookie.remove("refreshtoken");
          Cookie.set("refreshtoken", res.data.refresh_token);
          console.log(res);
          originalRequest.headers["Authorization"] =
            "Bearer " + res.data.access_token;
         return axios.request(originalRequest);
        })
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {/* <React.StrictMode> */}
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    {/* </React.StrictMode> */}
  </Provider>
);
```

I m trying to do navigation and  search about it a lot , but couldn't found out any way ,i try various way but no thing worked well so  any one have solution about it?

Comment: You could wrap all your routes which are shown post authentication with a parent component which checks for the conditions- if the user token doesn't exist, navigate the user to /logout. If the user is authenticated(token exists), then return the children. You must remove the token using the logout redux action.

Comment: did not get it !!

Comment: @arp......................

Comment: Which part did you not understand?

Comment: all part what u said above